# how to debug apple push notifications ot ios client when it shows no error on server

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I have a device token for an ios device as well as certificates and keys I've uploaded to pushwoosh as well as a node-apn service.  I send a push notification to my test device using its device token, and the server as well as pushwoosh show notification was sent without errors.

However I din't see the message on my test phone.

How can I debug this issue further when it looks like it's got the right device token and the apple push is not showing any errors on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like I was pushing with a sandbox cert and I didn't set my code signing identity to iosdeveloper rather than my distribution profile.